# Using XLRD module to search for a string on imported excel-file

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have an excel-file that is roughly 1000 rows and 25 columns wide.

What I want to do is to create a script that looks through the excel-file based on an user input. (names in this case)

My current code goes as following:

```
import xlrd
file_location =r"C:\Users\extoskben\Desktop\Datorer.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
User = input("What's the users name?:   ")
```

I want the code to read from the excel-file and print the result from all columns based on the name it matches with.

EDIT:

**Structure of the excel file :**

```
   [Name         ] [x] [x] [x] [Serialnumber] [x] [x] [   Model    ]
[1] Oskar Beneke    x   x   x   123456789      x   x  Thinkpad t470
[2] Example name    x   x   x   987654321      x   x  Thinkpad t470s
```

I would like to know how I can print out the results from only the Rows 1 5 and 8 and leave the "X's" out from my print.

Comment: How is your data structured? Are names on the first column of every row for example? This is a blind guess. If you provide more details it will be easier to answer, therefore you'll have more chances to get answers

Comment: Hello, each column reads as following: Name, Model, Username, Serialnumber, etc, and every row under that has information in each box. I know how to specifically choose which row I want the information from but the input and retrieving information from what i've answered part I am unsure of.

Comment: Name, X, Serialnumber are your columns not your row, the misinterpretation come from there. The answer is edited to add the answer about printing specific columns.

Comment: Ahh, I am very sorry, I totally mixed them together! 

That is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help and for your patience with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code does what you want :

```
import xlrd
file_location =r"C:\Users\extoskben\Desktop\Datorer.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
User = input("What's the users name?:   ")

for row in range(sheet.nrows):  # Iterate over every rows of the file
    if User == sheet.cell_value(row, 0):  # If the user name match the input
        for col in range(sheet.row_len(row)):  # Iterate over every columns of the cell
            print(str(sheet.cell_value(row, col)))  # Print the value of the cells.
```

**EDIT :**

If you want to print only specific columns (the first, fifth and eigth in this example) of the given rows, you can use this version of the for loop:

```
columns_to_output = [0, 4, 7]  # List of columns to ouptput (starting with `0` for first column index)
for row in range(sheet.nrows):  # Iterate over every rows of the file
    if User == sheet.cell_value(row, 0):  # If the user name match the input
        for col in columns_to_output:  # Iterate over the column to output list
            print(str(sheet.cell_value(row, col)))  # Printing the cell at given column in the row.
```

Comment: I assumed "I want the code to [...] print the result of all row matching" to mean you wanted to print all the value in the matching rows.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, perhaps I stated myself wrong here.

What I essentially want is to search for a name, Oskar Beneke for example, my name. The Serialnumber is on Row 3 in excel, and my name is on column 500. If I were to type in Oskar Beneke in the input, i want it to print my Serialnumber, I am sorry if I make things difficult,  I am quite new at this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually did this wrong on my part. Your code does work, it was just me that was a little bit confused. Now that I've got that covered, how can I specifically chose which Rows i want printed? For example, I'd want row 1, 3 and 7 to print when I enter the name.

Comment: I'm confused about your "rows" and "columns", maybe edit your question too show an example of a few lines and few columns of your xls. 
What I understand is that your row is the row in which you found the name, maybe you meant columns?

Comment: I've now updated the information in my question, I hope that it is more clear now.